Cache pages in Nextjs 12.3 in serversideprops
we want to cache our nextjs pages that is built with backend data with serversideprops. it's same data for every visitors. Now we have dynamic user data in app.tsx file and we push those data to redux store. We don't want to cache anything from app.tsx specially the auth states.. but we notice that the document is cached with all the app.tsx data..
is there any ways to bypass the app.tsx and only cache page generated by nextjs pages?

You can use getServerSideProps to control caching behavior on a per-page basis. For pages where you want caching, you can set appropriate cache-control headers to cache the HTML response, while dynamic content such as authentication and user data in app.tsx should not be cached.
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const data = await fetchDataFromBackend();

  // Set Cache-Control headers for the SSR response
  context.res.setHeader(
    'Cache-Control',
    'public, s-maxage=600, stale-while-revalidate=59'
  );

  return {
    props: { data }, // The data will be passed to the page component as props
  };
}

export default function MyPage({ data }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Render your cached page content here */}
      <h1>{data.title}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

Avoid caching in app.tsx.
The caching issues arise when dynamic data within app.tsx gets cached along with the page. Here’s how you can ensure that app.tsx doesn't cache sensitive data:
Isolate Auth and User-Specific Logic: Ensure that user-specific data is either fetched client-side or revalidated during each request.
Disable Cache for App-level Data: You can use getServerSideProps in a page-level component but avoid setting cache-control headers for dynamic data in app.tsx

we are doing same, but this page also add everything from app.tsx which is the problem.. we have to avoid caching auth data used in app.tsx

You can check my updated ans to avoid catching
